# Save multiple checkboxes with Types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, user-meta

I'm using Types plugin to create user metaboxes but it doesn't save. My HTML:

```
<form id="new-user" action="" method="POST" name="new-user" novalidate="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="wpcf-nombre-u" id="nombre" placeholder="<?php _e('Nombre', 'wm'); ?>" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="wpcf-apellidos-u" id="apellidos" placeholder="<?php _e('Apellidos', 'wm'); ?>" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" name="wpcf-contrasena-u" id="contrasena" placeholder="<?php _e('Contraseña', 'wm'); ?>" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" name="wpcf-rep-contrasena-u" id="rep-contrasena" placeholder="<?php _e('Repita contraseña', 'wm'); ?>" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" name="wpcf-email-u" id="email" placeholder="Email" >
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sectores[]" id="sector-nutricion-deportiva" value="nutricion-deportiva">
        <label for="sector-nutricion-deportiva">Nutrición deportiva</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="sectores[]" id="sector-rutinas-de-gimnasio" value="rutinas-de-gimnasio">
        <label for="sector-rutinas-de-gimnasio">Rutinas de gimnasio</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="sectores[]" id="sector-clases-dirigidas" value="clases-dirigidas">
        <label for="sector-clases-dirigidas">Clases dirigidas</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="sectores[]" id="sector-entrenamiento-personal" value="entrenamiento-personal">
        <label for="sector-entrenamiento-personal">Entrenamiento personal</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="sectores[]" id="sector-deportes-de-equipo" value="deportes-de-equipo">
        <label for="sector-deportes-de-equipo">Deportes de equipo</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="sectores[]" id="sector-deportes-individuales" value="deportes-individuales">
        <label for="sector-deportes-individuales">Deportes individuales</label>

        <input type="submit" value="¡Registrate ya!" />
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="register" />

    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$err = '';
$success = '';

global $wpdb, $PasswordHash, $current_user, $user_ID;

if( isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'register' ) {
  $nombre = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['wpcf-nombre-u']));
  $apellidos = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['wpcf-apellidos-u']));
  $contrasena = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['wpcf-contrasena-u']));
  $rep_contrasena = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['wpcf-rep-contrasena-u']));
  $email = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['wpcf-email-u']));

  if( $email == "" || $contrasena == "" || $rep_contrasena == "" || $username == "" || $nombre == "" || $apellidos == "") {
    $err = 'Please don\'t leave the required fields.';
  } else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $err = 'Invalid email address.';
  } else if(email_exists($email) ) {
    $err = 'Email already exist.';
  } else if($contrasena <> $rep_contrasena ){
    $err = 'Password do not match.';
  } else {
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( 
        array (
            'first_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $nombre), 
            'last_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_last_name', $apellidos), 
            'user_pass' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $contrasena), 
            'user_login' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $username),
            'user_email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email), 'role' => 'subscriber' 
        ) 
    );

    if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
        $err = 'Error on user creation.';
    } else {
        $success = 'You\'re successfully register';
        $sectores = $_POST['sectores'];
        $count = count($sectores);
        for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
          update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wpcf-sectores-de-experiencia-u', $sectores[$i] );
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My types backend is:
[image]

Comment: please provide more complete code, where is this code called, which function / hook are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I edit my code

Comment: is the user registered successfully? are the other fields used in the code part of the same form?

Comment: The user is registered and the others fields are saving successfully. The other fields are in the same form. I change the HTML to show them.

Comment: don;t call `do_action('user_register', $user_id);`, that is handled by https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/. the userdata may be saving just the last value because you are using the same key.

Comment: I remove the action hook but still not working

Comment: have you tried using separate keys for the user meta?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `apply_filters()` and just pass the array values into your `wp_insert_user`:

```
array(
   'first_name' => $nombre, 
   'last_name'  => $apellidos, 
   'user_pass'  => $contrasena, 
   'user_login' => $username,
   'user_email' => $email,
   'role'       => 'subscriber',
)
```

WordPress already managed those `apply_filters`, so there's no reason to use them in your code.

Hope it helps! Me dices si te sirvió, también hablo español. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple values for the same key by using [`add_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) and setting the last parameter `$unique` to `false`:

```
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
  add_user_meta($user_id, 'wpcf-sectores-de-experiencia-u', $sectores[$i], false);
}
```

If you wish to use [`update_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) you can use separate keys for each checkbox:

```
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
  update_user_meta($user_id, $sectores[$i], '1');
}
```

However, since unchecked checkboxes are not submitted, updates will have to check for missing keys and remove them. A simpler way therefore would be to just save the array directly:

```
update_user_meta($user_id, 'wpcf-sectores-de-experiencia-u', $sectores);
```

And you can check if a value has been checked by using [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$sectores = get_user_meta($user_id, 'wpcf-sectores-de-experiencia-u', true);
if(in_array('clases-dirigidas', $sectores)) {
  //do something
}
```